# Select records where difference between datetime column1 and column 2 is greater than X amount of time

Tags: mysql, datetime

As the title indicates, I'm trying to return records where the datetime difference between two datetime columns is greater than X amount of time. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this concept. I know how to do where column1 is greater than column2, but not calculate the difference between columns and then return results that are greater than or less than a specific amount.

I have built the schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1effe

Can I get some help on this? Basically I'm trying to get records from this table where the difference between publish_date and submission_date is greater than X amount of time, like 1 hour for example. Can I get a hand with this please? I don't even know where to begin.

I'm thinking this is what I want but I'm not sure

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  test_table
WHERE
  timestampdiff(hour, publish_date, submission_date) > 1
```

Comment: Your syntax is right, you can also use `timestampdiff(minute, publish_date, submission_date) BETWEEN 60 AND XXXX`.

Comment: You should add an index on `publish_date,submission_date`.

Comment: What do you mean add an index?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE test_table ADD INDEX(publish_date, submission_date)`.  (But I doubt if it will help in this case.)